# SOLID Principles, Can JDBC interface be said as an example of Dependency Inversion Principle?

Tags: solid-principles, dependency-inversion

Of the five SOLID Principles, Dependency Inversion is one of them and the last one.

Can I quote `JDBC` interface as an example of Dependency Inversion Principle?

Comment: I am sorry, but JDBC is a big thingy. Can you please provide an MRE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

JDBC at its essence is a giant instance of the [Adapter design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter). While it may use Dependency Inversion somewhere in its implementation, this isn't what it's essentially about.

Comment: Can you point out a specific JDBC class that implements the Adapter pattern?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of JDBC, but it maps the high-level API the developer uses to the interface provided by the database, and this essentially is an example of Adaption.